# Divide 500 into certain group so that all no's 1 to 500 can be found.

Tags: combinatorics

500 coins are there.
Divide 500 coins into certain bags such that any rupees from 1 to 500 can be found by the combination of the bag's coins.
What are the minimum nos of bags ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I can have $500$ bags with a rupee in each. Or I can have bags with $1, 2, 4, 8 \dots$ Rupees and compute values using the binary system. Or I could have $1, 3, 9 \dots$ if I am allowed $2=3-1$. Or I could use typical coin denominations of $1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50 \dots$ - what is allowed, and do you want the least number of bags, or to count the number of ways you can get to $500$?

Comment: Am I guessing correctly that you want to partition a set of coins having values $1...500$ such that each subset is capable of producing every value in the range $1..500$?

Comment: I could have many bags and bags contain rupees like 1,3,5.... and 2=3-1 is allowed.

Comment: Do we get to choose what kind of coins are there, or do we have to work with specific kinds? Also, why did you tag (prime-numbers)? Are they relevant for some reason?

Comment: We are allowed to choose what kind of coins are there ? i am in doubt that it's solution is related to prime numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are not allowed to subtract the numbers, just add them.  In that case, having the bags with powers of $2$ is optimal.  If you are allowed to subtract them as well, powers of $3$.  The last bag won't follow the pattern, and provides flexibility to the rest.

Comment: It would be immense help , if you explain further: How bags with powers 2|3 are optimal ?

Comment: Think about three bags $1,2,4$.  You can make anything up to $7$.  If subtraction is allowed, $1,3,9$ and you can make anything up to $13$

Comment: @Learner: Are you familiar with binary (base two) notation?